# java basics related to inheritance

Tags: java

I am new to java below question may sound to be stupid but i am not able to figure it out as what went wrong.

below is the program i have written.

```
public class AccessDemo1{
    public int a_pub=2;
    private int a_pri=3;
    int a_def=4;
    protected int a_pro=5;

    Public AccessDemo1(){
        System.out.println("Value of a_pub = " + a_pub);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pri = " + a_pri);
        System.out.println("Value of a_def = " + a_def);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pro = " + a_pro);
    }
}

//package p1;

public class AccessDemo2 extends AccessDemo1{

    AccessDemo2(){
    }

    Public AccessDemo2(){
        System.out.println("Value of a_pub = " + a_pub);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pri = " + a_pri);
        System.out.println("Value of a_def = " + a_def);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pro = " + a_pro);
    }
}

//package p1;

public class demomain{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        AccessDemo2 ob1 = new AccessDemo2();

    }

}
```

On compiling the demomain class it give s me below error.Why so

```
demomain.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
AccessDemo2 ob1 = new AccessDemo2();
```

So after going through all the suggestion i made below changes. i break the code in to three diffrent files each holding one class as shown below.

file AccessDemo1.java with below content

```
package p1;

public class AccessDemo1{
    public int a_pub=2;
    private int a_pri=3;
    int a_def=4;
    protected int a_pro=5;

    public AccessDemo1(){
        System.out.println("Value of a_pub = " + a_pub);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pri = " + a_pri);
        System.out.println("Value of a_def = " + a_def);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pro = " + a_pro);
    }
}
```

File AccessDemo2.java with below content

```
package p1;

public class AccessDemo2 extends AccessDemo1{

    public AccessDemo2(){
        System.out.println("Value of a_pub = " + a_pub);
        //System.out.println("Value of a_pri = " + a_pri);
        System.out.println("Value of a_def = " + a_def);
        System.out.println("Value of a_pro = " + a_pro);
    }
}
```

and last file like demomain.java

```
package p1;

public class demomain{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        AccessDemo2 ob1 = new AccessDemo2();

    }

}
```

Now next problem is that i am able to compile and run the code if i am commenting the package statement in all the files.But if i include that as shown in above examples then on compiling the demomain.java i am getting below errors.

```
D:\javastudy>javac demomain.java
demomain.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
AccessDemo2 ob1 = new AccessDemo2();
^
  symbol:   class AccessDemo2
  location: class demomain
demomain.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
AccessDemo2 ob1 = new AccessDemo2();
                      ^
  symbol:   class AccessDemo2
  location:

 class demomain
2 errors
```

What is the possible reason for this is there some other way of compiling the files that include package statement ?Please guide me

Comment: Always avoid no-name package.

Comment: Yes all code is in single file.

Comment: Did your AccessDemo2 compile? Are you able to create object of AccessDemo1? Why is the P capital in "Public AccessDemo2(){" constructor ?

Comment: I don't think so. There must be single public class per source file.

Comment: yes i avoid no name package i was using package p1 but later commented those lines as i thought package may be causing issue.sure i will never use no name packages

Comment: Once you get past this, you'll find thst AccessDemo2 itself won't compile, as it won't be allowed to use a_pri .

Comment: What is this `Public AccessDemo1()` `Public` with title case.

Comment: Thanks all for correcting me.I tried again and have modified my code but now facing strange issue after use of package statement.I have edited my question above and have added few more lines please correct me again.

Comment: The title of this question talks about inheritance.  I don't think inheritance has anything to do with your error.  Does it?

Comment: Are you compiling all of the source files one-by-one in order of dependency, compiling them altogether or only doing the top-level one?  If you are only compiling demomain.java and expecting the compiler to discover the other .java source files, it won't do that.

Comment: `package P1;` `package p1;` this may be the problem ? bcus package names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams problem is not with your code, it is with the **folder/package** structure you are using

```
D:\javastudy>javac demomain.java
```

This command tells me that you **do not** have any package named `p1` physically created. This is the reason that you are able to run your code without package statement but not with package statement.

In order to fix the package issue you need to **create a folder** under `javastudy` named `p1 (as this is your package name)` and **move all three** classes to that folder.And then try to compile using :

```
D:\javastudy>javac p1\demomain.java
```

And run is using:

```
D:\javastudy>java p1.demomain
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it helped you then kindly accept as answer.  Hv fun coding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to have two constructors with the same signature for `AccessDemo2`.  Also, you have misspelt `public` twice.  Remove the first constructor

```
AccessDemo2(){
}
```

since you already have another one.  And change `Public` to `public` everywhere.

Comment: what about this comments - *Yes all code is in single file.* multiple public classes in the same file.

Comment: That comment was only posted 7 seconds before my answer.  I don't go and retrospectively fix stuff that's not in the question at the time that I see it.

Comment: Thanks  for correcting me.I tried again and have modified my code but now facing strange issue after use of package statement.I have edited my question above and have added few more lines please correct me again.

Comment: Your classes are in 2 different packages: P1 and p1, notice the case differences.  Try fixing that.

Comment: Corrected the mistake but still same issue

Comment: @Brandon I have fixed package name error but still compilation of class gives error

Comment: All classes are in same package then why class with main method is not able to find AccessDemo2 .
if i am running the program without package statement in all three classes then program is running fine. what m i missing

Comment: Are your files in a directory called `p1`?  The directory structure of your source files has to match the package structure of the classes.